# PHP AppEngine - last_cursor is broken

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When using https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds, the end_cursor returned by appengine appears to be using non-utf characters. Any suggestions here?

["end_cursor"]=>
  string(247) "
�

date  ��������js~app-namer�Class"�randomcharactershtm� "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to base64 encode the returned cursor and make it websafe using the following functions:

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
 return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```